# Poor performance on Linux compared to Windows when reading from certain USB 3 flash drives

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel-modules, usb-drive

The issue to which I refer has been talked about a bit elsewhere on the internet:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/sbpt23/usb_flash_drive_read_speed_much_slower_in_linux/
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=328360
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbNNs-oyuTQ
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ujwlmn/slow_read_speed_with_samsung_fit_plus_drive_on/

However, it doesn't seem that anyone has found a solution.

I am fairly sure this is not a "Windows is lying/Linux is telling the truth" kind of issue. It is not a drive health issue, as the same drive works 5x as fast under Windows than on Linux on the same computer, in the same port.

I also do not think it's related to the filesystem the drive is formatted with, for reasons shown below.

I think there is something wrong in the way that Linux (and/or the drivers) is communicating with these drives that causes them not to reach their full capability.

In my particular case, the drive is a [Samsung USB Type-C™ Flash Drive 128GB (MUF-128DA/AM)](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/usb-flash-drives/usb-type-c-128gb-muf-128da-am/).

In Windows, using CrystalDiskMark, it's possible to get sequential read speeds on the order of 400MB/s:

[image: CrystalDiskMark benchmark of the flash drive]

In Linux, this is the best read speed I could get:

```
$ dd iflag=direct if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=128k count=1500
1500+0 records in
1500+0 records out
196608000 bytes (197 MB, 188 MiB) copied, 2.3547 s, 83.5 MB/s
```

I tried various block sizes and count. I also tried `fio` and `hdparm`. Both returned similar speeds of around 84 MB/s. Also note that this is reading directly from /dev/sda, and not a partition or even a file on the drive (I get similar speeds, though, when reading from a file).

Here are some details of the drive:

```
$ lsusb -t
...
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M

$ lsusb -d 090c:1000 -v

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x090c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)
  idProduct          0x1000 Flash Drive
  bcdDevice           11.00
  iManufacturer           1 Samsung
  iProduct                2 Type-C
  iSerial                 3 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002c
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              304mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               8
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               8
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x0016
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      HIRD Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000c
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   2
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is High Speed (480Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat           4 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

What would be the best way to approach getting to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to use a larger buffer size? For example 1GiB?

Comment: Yes, as I said I tried various block sizes with `dd` and `fio`, including 1GB. All variations (except for very small block sizes) returned similar results.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this difference. On my workstation, which has dualboot Windows 11 and Debian 11, USB speeds are nearly the same. I used exFAT filesystem on my USB drive, using default values of Windows 11 for formatting. I created a 1GiB large random file and copied the file within both operating systems from same USB drive at same USB port to my much faster internal SSD and measured the time. Linux Bash `time bash -c "cp -v random.dat /tmp/ ; sync"`, Windows Powershell `Measure-Command { cp -v random.dat c:\tmp\ }` - of course I'm using different hardware, I had just 100MiB/s

Comment: I would guess, you have either no USB-3 drivers in Linux, your drivers are generally not working in a correct way, or your testing is wrong. You should test on another computer too. What Linux distribution do you use?

Comment: It's worth mentioning the system can't lie about read speed.  If you haven't read the info you don't get the data.  It's write speed that gets lied about through buffering.